# How to compress rows after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have performed a groupby on my dataframe.

```
grouped = data_df.groupby(['Cluster','Visit Number Final'])['Visitor_ID'].count()
```

I am getting the below output :

```
data_df.groupby(['Cluster','Visit Number Final'])['Visitor_ID'].count()
```

Out[81]:

```
    Cluster  Visit Number Final
    0        1                     21846
             2                      1485
             3                       299
             4                        95
             5                        24
             6                         8
             7                         3
    1        1                     33600
             2                      2283
             3                       404
             4                       117
             5                        34
             6                         7
    2        1                      5858
             2                       311
             3                        55
             4                        14
             5                         6
             6                         3
             7                         1
    3        1                     19699
             2                      1101
             3                       214
             4                        78
             5                        14
             6                         8
             7                         3
    4        1                     10086
             2                       344
             3                        59
             4                        14
             5                         3
             6                         1
    Name: Visitor_ID, dtype: int64
```

Now i want to compress the rows whose Visit Number Final >3(Add a new row which has the summation for visit number final 4,5,6). I am trying groupby.filter but not getting the expected output. 
My final output should look like

```
Cluster  Visit Number Final 

    0        1                     21846 
             2                      1485 
             3                       299 
           >=4                       130 

    1        1                     33600 
             2                      2283 
             3                       404 
           >=4                       158 

    2        1                      5858 
             2                       311 
             3                        55 
           >=4                        24 

    3        1                     19699 
             2                      1101 
             3                       214 
           >=4                       103 

    4        1                     10086 
             2                       344 
             3                        59 
           >=4                        18
```

Comment: You need a [MCVE]. You haven't even asked a question yet.

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to archieve? What have to tried and found so far?

Comment: I want to sum the rows where visit number final is greater than 3. So under each cluster i will have a row corresponding to the count of  Visit 1,2,3,>3

Comment: Show the expected dataframe

Comment: Cluster  Visit Number Final 

0        1                     21846 

         2                      1485 

         3                       299 

        > =4                        130 

1        1                     33600 

         2                      2283 

         3                       404 

         >=4                       158 

2        1                      5858 

         2                       311 

         3                        55 

         >=4                        24

Comment: Updated the expected dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace the 'Visit Number Final' values bigger than 3, before you group the dataframe:

```
df.loc[df['Visit Number Final'] > 3, 'Visit Number Final'] = '>=4'
df.groupby(['Cluster','Visit Number Final'])['Visitor_ID'].count()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
visit_val = df.index.get_level_values(1)
grp = np.where((visit_val <= 3) == 0, '>=4', visit_val)

(df.groupby(['Cluster',grp])['Number Final'].sum()
   .reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Visit'}))
```

Output:

```
    Cluster Visit  Number Final
0         0     1         21846
1         0     2          1485
2         0     3           299
3         0   >=4           130
4         1     1         33600
5         1     2          2283
6         1     3           404
7         1   >=4           158
8         2     1          5858
9         2     2           311
10        2     3            55
11        2   >=4            24
12        3     1         19699
13        3     2          1101
14        3     3           214
15        3   >=4           103
16        4     1         10086
17        4     2           344
18        4     3            59
19        4   >=4            18
```

Or to get dataframe with indexes:

```
(df.groupby(['Cluster',grp])['Number Final'].sum()
   .rename_axis(['Cluster','Visit']).to_frame())
```

Output:

```
               Number Final
Cluster Visit              
0       1             21846
        2              1485
        3               299
        >=4             130
1       1             33600
        2              2283
        3               404
        >=4             158
2       1              5858
        2               311
        3                55
        >=4              24
3       1             19699
        2              1101
        3               214
        >=4             103
4       1             10086
        2               344
        3                59
        >=4              18
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped

Comment: I have but it won't show publicly since i have less points. I have just joined this community